# Getting data from public API in server and send to Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

Here's another possibly easy issue but one that is stumping me nonetheless. I am pretty familiar with making api calls in the front end and displaying the data however I want to be secure so I am trying to move the api call to the backend server file. I seem to be having some difficulties displaying the information that the API call from the backend is sending to the front. And actually the function on the client side that calls the server is displaying pending in the console. The data is being console.logged in the backend and is working correctly but how do I retrieve that data in the front end? The function in question is the loadProfile function.

Server file;

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('axios');

router.get('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(
      `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news?category=general&token=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    );

    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Client Side:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import NewsCard from '../News/NewsCard';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import PostForm from '../PostForm/PostForm';
import './Profile.css';

const Profile = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProfile();
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const loadProfile = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/profile');
    console.log(res.data);
    setItems(res.data);
  };

  const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/post');
      setPosts(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="profileBody">
      <div className="news">
        <NewsCard key={posts.idPosts} items={items} />
      </div>

      <div className="postSection">
        <PostForm getPosts={getPosts} />
        <h1>
          Latest Posts{' '}
          <span onClick={getPosts}>
            <i class="fas fa-redo"> </i>
          </span>
        </h1>

        <div>
          <Post key={posts.id} posts={posts} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="prices">
        <h3>hewiorhewioajroiewja</h3>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not returning the response from backend `return res.json(data);` :

```
router.get('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(
      `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news?category=general&token=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    );

    console.log(data);
    return res.json(data); // missing return
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...when I add the return I'm getting a type error that says:

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/Users/jenki/Desktop/Desktop/Personal Projects/socialMediaStock/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)

Comment: What format of data is returned by `api/v1/news?`?

Comment: From the docs it looks like it should be an array of objects

Comment: So I found another person's solution that involved using a .then after the call. I guess i'm confused because I thought when you await something you don't need to use .then